# Why does touchmove not fire on html canvas?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, canvas

I'm using an angular app, where the user has a canvas, and can draw rectangles on that canvas.

My touchstart and touchend are firing, but touchmove is not. I'm not sure if I'm not understanding how touchmove works. I was assuming it would be equivalent to mousemove.

```
  self.canvas.addEventListener('touchmove', (e) => { self.touchMove(e); });
  self.canvas.addEventListener('touchstart', (e) => { self.touchStart(e); });  // touch down event
  self.canvas.addEventListener('touchend', (e) => { self.touchEnd(e); }); //



  touchStart(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    const self = this;
    const activeTag = self.TagService.activeTags[0];
    this.canvasState.doTouchStart(e, activeTag, (shape) => {
      self.selection = shape;
    });
  }


  touchEnd(e) {
    const self = this;
    // console.log(this);//is the controller
    const activeTag = self.TagService.activeTags[0];
    self.canvasState.doTouchEnd(e, activeTag, function doTouchUp(shape) { 
      self.selection = shape;
      self.addShape(shape);
      // console.log(self.shapes);
    });
  }

  touchmove(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log("HERE HERE HERE");
    const self = this;
    const activeTag = self.TagService.activeTags[0];
    this.canvasState.doTouchMove(e, activeTag, (shape) => {
      let len = self.shapes.length;
      self.addShape(shape);
      let len2 = self.shapes.length;
      if (len2 - len === 1) {
        self.draw();
        self.shapes.splice(-1, 1);
      }
    });
  }
```

The touchstart and touchend work, but touch move never fires. I can never get the console output.

Edit: I changed the first line to be `touchmove`, as there was touchMove and touchmove (typo), but that still does not fire the touchmove.
Also, I get `Ignored attempt to cancel a touchstart event with    cancelable=false, for example because scrolling is in progress and cannot be interrupted.` warning when I try to draw something down. This is really strange, because I tried the same thing in a non-angular app (Very simple canvas interactions), and I didn't get that error. It blocked me from scrolling, and instead drew stuff on the canvas.

Answer (score 0):

If you review your code, when you add a listener in this line:

```
self.canvas.addEventListener('touchmove', (e) => { self.touchMove(e); });
```

you're calling the function `self.touchMove(e)` and more below at the code you're declaring your function as  `touchmove(e)`, Here is a great library that it helps you to handle touch events  [Hammerjs](http://hammerjs.github.io/#try-it)

Comment: yeah I changed it to be touchmove in both places, but it's still not firing. I even put `self.canvas.addEventListener('touchmove', (e) => { console.log("hi"); self.touchMove(e); });` And hi doesn't print out.

Comment: @welc0meToTheMachine How are you testing your code?

Comment: What do you mean? I'm just trying to emulate the events I already have through mouse interactions, and testing if functions run through console log, and debugger statements. And I'm trying the app out using dev tools, and changing the display to tablet/mobile (the two screens icon)